# What is the fastest way to fetch the last row from a table?

Tags: postgresql, physical-design

I have a PostgreSQL table, `Prices`, with the columns:

- `price` (Decimal)
- `product_id` (Int)

There are also `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

Prices get updated regularly and I keep old prices in the table. For a given product, the last price in the table is the current price.

What is the most efficient way to get the last price for a specific product:

- Index `product_id` and query for the last record
- Add a third column `active` (Boolean) to mark the latest price and create a composite index (`product_id` and `active`)
- Or something else?

Comment: Using a partial index with the condition `where active` would probably help even more to retrieve the latest product.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need an index on product_id regardless of solution.

Provided you have an index on the updated_at column, and all you need is to fetch "a specific product" as you stated, then I would do:

```
select *
from Prices
where product_id = ?
order by updated_at desc 
limit 1
```

But if I did not get the results I wanted or if I needed to get the current price for many products, then I would try the option of adding a active column, and setting it to N for all prices other than the new one when doing updates of the prices and then I would create a partial index where active as suggested by a_horse_with_no_name. I would go there only if I needed to as it adds a layer of complexity of updating previous price rows to not be active, etc.

Comment: This query needs an index on `(product_id, updated_at)` - or on  `(product_id, updated_at DESC)` - to be efficient. Not just on  `(updated_at)`.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowledge of the rest of your database, you can afford a bit of non normal form to speed up products price fetching (assuming there is one price for each item).

Just create a new column named `last_price`of type `price` in your `product` table and create a trigger `AFTER INSERT ON EACH ROW`on your `price` table. Every time a new price is created, it updates the related product with the latest price. This way, every time you fetch a product, you also fetch its last price.

Since version 9.3, PostgreSQL supports materialized views. This is a nice way to denormalize the data, keeping a normal form for writing and denormalized view for reading. The update of the view can be triggered by Postgres’ LISTEN/NOTIFY mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

You do should have a column of wef date and time (with effect from) in price table. User will enter its value while updating price. After that fetch only value with desc wef limit 1.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: selected answer is the same as my answer only have some more explaining.